# how to groupby and keep dataframe type instead of series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to group a dataframe to get the min 'vid' value for each 'pid'.(Each 'pid' has multiple 'vid' and I want to keep the lowest per 'pid').

The problem is that I need the output in data frame, and the groupby operation changes my output to a series. Even if I try to change back to dataframe using 'to_frame()', the shape is showing me 1 columns instead of 2. It's treating 'pid' as the index.

```
hf_patients_min_visit=filtered_hf_patients.groupby('pid')['vid'].min()
hf_patients_min_visit.to_frame()
```

[image]

If I don't use 'to_frame()', I have a series. but I need a data frame with shape 2960,2
[image]

Comment: use `reset_index` instead `to_frame`

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables). You might need to use `print(<df>)` to get the formatting right.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you need to use `reset_index()` function :

```
hf_patients_min_visit=filtered_hf_patients.groupby('pid')['vid'].min()
hf_patients_min_visit.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `as_index=False` to the `.groupby` function will return your groupings as a column instead of an `Index`.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({
    'group': [*'AAABBBCCC'],
    'value': [*range(9)],
})

print(
    df.groupby('group', as_index=False)['value'].min()
)
#   group  value
# 0     A      0
# 1     B      3
# 2     C      6
```